# Cannot connect to Mosquitto broker

Tags: mqtt

I am trying to establish a connection to my 'localhost' Mosquitto broker from javascript using Paho library. 
I cannot seem to make it work. Probably the .conf file needs some adjustment.

Tried to connect to my local Mosquitto broker, using javascript below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.1/mqttws31.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script> 
function btnclk(){
alert ("Will try to connect");
var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("localhost",1883,"00001");

var options = {

     //connection attempt timeout in seconds
     timeout: 3,

     //Gets Called if the connection has successfully been established
     onSuccess: function () {
         alert("Connected");
     },

     //Gets Called if the connection could not be established
     onFailure: function (message) {
         alert("Connection failed: " + message.errorMessage);
     }
      };

//Attempt to connect
client.connect(options);


}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<p>
<button type="button" onclick="btnclk()">Connect</button>
</p>


</body>
</html>
```

The mosquitto.conf file is the typical with the following lines added:

```
listener 1883
protocol mqtt

listener 8080
protocol websockets
```

The result I get is:

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:1883/mqtt' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

when trying to connect to localhost on port 1883 and

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/mqtt' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

when trying to connect to port 8080

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Confirm your webserver isn’t already running on port 8080 - with rabbitmq stopped, see if there is a listener on 8080 using e.g. `netstat -a -p tcp`

Comment: ok, so I added the following (on config):

Under Default listener:

bind_address 127.0.0.1

port 1883

So, after that, for a reason I don't understand, the connection was established on port 8080

If anyone can explain why It would be most appreciated.